# jpa: how can i map with interitance with self-referencing

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have some class like this

```kotlin
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn
class Foo(@Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
          var id: Long?,
          val name: String)

@Entity
class IntFoo(id: Long? = null, name: String, val value: Int): Foo(id, name)

@Entity
class StringFoo(id: Long? = null, name: String, val value: String): Foo(id, name)

@Entity
class ComplexFoo(id: Long? = null,name: String, @OneToMany val values: List<Foo>): Foo(id, name)
```

and I inserted data like this

```kotlin
        val intFoo = IntFoo(name = "int", value = 1)
        intFooRepository.save(intFoo)
        
        val stringFoo = StringFoo(name = "string", value = "String")
        stringFooRepository.save(stringFoo)
        
        val complexFoo = ComplexFoo(name = "complex", values = listOf(intFoo, stringFoo))
        complexFooRepository.save(complexFoo)
```

but table `complex_foo_values` created with out Foo's property and also insert not works

```
create table complex_foo (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
create table complex_foo_values (complex_foo_id bigint not null, values_id bigint not null)
create table foo (dtype varchar(31) not null, id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
create table int_foo (value integer not null, id bigint not null, primary key (id))
create table string_foo (value varchar(255), id bigint not null, primary key (id))

insert into complex_foo_values (complex_foo_id, values_id) values (?, ?)
```

what show i do for this?

Comment: i just find out ways thanks!